# Jmeter : Stress test configuration with multiple user systems pointed to enterprise application

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

We have 2 applications: 
1. A standalone application(java application) running on user system 
2. Web-application

To create a stress test script as in real-production scenario. I would like to clone multiple user-system's which would communicate with the web-application.

Is there any way I could to that with Jmeter or any other tool.

I am new to Jmeter & stress-testing as I am a developer. So I apologize for naive questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup jmeter in distributed environment. follow the steps in the document shared below.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

In order to test the standalone Java application, you can do one of the following:
1. you can make a jar of your application
2. if your application accepts arguments, your can use OS sampler to call your jar with arguments.
3. otherwise, you can copy the jar to lib/ext folder of jmeter and use Beanshell sampler to import your lib/jar and create the test by calling all the methods.

hope this will help.

Comment: My Java application is a JAR and it takes arguments. So with OS-sampler: Would it only one instance in a slave machine. My intention is to create 1000 instances of this java-application

Comment: By 1000 instances do you mean 1000 concurrent user load.
In the above case, that can be maintained from the Thread Group level

   Thread Group
     -- OS Process Sampler
    Listener

Comment: yes i meant 1000 concurrent user load but each instance of the java-application should start with a different argument ex: test.jar test1ID, test.jar test2ID so on..., would this be possible.

Comment: yes, you can create a csv file with all the values and using "CSV Data set config" define a variable e.g. "arg". 
Pass this variable as ${arg}, in the OS Process sampler.
using this setup, jmeter will pass different value to each user as arguments defined by you in csv file.

Comment: Sample Jmeter file for OS Process Sampler: http://www24.zippyshare.com/v/21473517/file.html